# Multiprocesing pool.join() hangs under some circumstances

Tags: python, multiprocessing, producer-consumer, pool

I am trying to create  a simple producer / consumer pattern in Python using `multiprocessing`. It works, but it hangs on `poll.join()`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue

que = Queue()


def consume():
    while True:
        element = que.get()
        if element is None:
            print('break')
            break
    print('Consumer closing')


def produce(nr):
    que.put([nr] * 1000000)
    print('Producer {} closing'.format(nr))


def main():
    p = Pool(5)
    p.apply_async(consume)
    p.map(produce, range(5))
    que.put(None)
    print('None')
    p.close()
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
~/Python/Examples $ ./multip_prod_cons.py 
Producer 1 closing
Producer 3 closing
Producer 0 closing
Producer 2 closing
Producer 4 closing
None
break
Consumer closing
```

**However**, it works perfectly when I change one line:

```
que.put([nr] * 100)
```

It is 100% reproducible on Linux system running Python 3.4.3 or Python 2.7.10. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a lot of confusion here. What you are writing is not a producer/consumer scenario but a mess which is misusing another pattern usually referred as "pool of workers".

The pool of workers pattern is an application of the producer/consumer one in which there is one producer which schedules the work and many consumers which consume it. In this pattern, the owner of the `Pool` ends up been the producer while the workers will be the consumers.

In your example instead you have a hybrid solution where one worker ends up being a consumer and the others act as sort of middle-ware. The whole design is very inefficient, duplicates most of the logic already provided by the `Pool` and, more important, is very error prone. What you end up suffering from, is a [Deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Putting an object into a `multiprocessing.Queue` is an asynchronous operation. It blocks only if the `Queue` is full and your `Queue` has infinite size.

This means your `produce` function returns immediately therefore the call to `p.map` is not blocking as you expect it to do. The related worker processes instead, wait until the actual message goes through the `Pipe` which the `Queue` uses as communication channel.

What happens next is that you terminate prematurely your consumer as you put in the `Queue` the `None` "message" which gets delivered before all the lists your `produce` function create are properly pushed through the `Pipe`.

You notice the issue once you call `p.join` but the real situation is the following.

- the `p.join` call is waiting for all the worker processes to terminate.
- the worker processes are waiting for the big lists to go though the `Queue`'s `Pipe`.
- as the consumer worker is long gone, nobody drains the `Pipe` which is obviously full.

The issue does not show if your lists are small enough to go through before you actually send the termination message to the `consume` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I agree with most of the points here, but I am curious. I the real application, producers do a lot of computationally intensive work, before the result is pushed to the queue, and consumer stores the results in the database. Can you explain a bit more how "The whole design is very inefficient, duplicates most of the logic already provided by the Pool"?

Comment: The `Pool` already creates an internal `Queue` which uses to dispatch the Tasks to the Workers. The Workers are simply processes waiting on the internal `Queue` and calling the given function once a new Task is scheduled. In your example you are using yet another `Queue` controlled by one of the Workers to dispatch the job to the other 4. You are litterally doing the whole job twice :)

Comment: The correct design would let your Workers do the computationally intensive job and return the results to the caller which would then store the results in the DB. Your parent process would act as a scheduler and results manager. In case the DB storage action would be a concern due to heavy I/O, you could the pass the results to a `Pool` of Threads allowing you to scale both on the CPU and I/O aspects of your service.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it.